Super Capacitor bank Design for Battery Swap
We need to maintain approximately 4-5 A at a max DC voltage of 84 V for 15 s or less.
Is this possible and how many super caps or banks of super caps will it take?
We have an electric motor and controller running off a 20S14P Lithium battery at 84 V max and low voltage after discharge of approx. 65 V.
We are doing a hot swap battery exchange, and with the current capacitors inside the controller we only have about 4 seconds before the controller shuts down and we have to do a restart.
We would like to extend the shutdown time by at least 10 seconds so the controller never shuts off before having the old battery out and a new battery connected.
Plugging another battery into the system before removing the discharged on will not work because we never know exactly what the voltage will be. To much of a spike or discharge for a lithium battery.

Do you initiate the swap at the low voltage setpoint? If not, what is the lowest voltage at which you would realistically swap batteries? What is the voltage at which the controller shuts down, if different?

what about using a SPDT switch to select between the two batteries? ... the cutover would be a few hundreds of milliseconds

What is the problem you're trying to solve? Is it the controller rebooting, or the motor stopping?

The controller is rebooting and shutting down in the period of a few seconds(4). Not enough time to swap batteries. After which it takes several seconds or up to a minute to restart.   If we can supply  power to the system for no more than 30 more seconds this would solve our issue. The voltage at swap times varies in each swap and the controller shuts down as the internal caps discharge.

Rough calculation
5 Amps x 20 Sec = 100 Coulombs of charge
80 Volts / 5 Amps = 16 Ohms DC resistance of the load
100 Coulombs / 80 Volts = 1.25 Farads
16 Ohms x 1.25 Farads = 20 seconds time constant
Allow 10% voltage drop in 20 seconds
Capacitor sizing 1.25 x 20/2 = 12.5 Farads minimum at 150 Volts minimum
This will require a whole helluva lot of low voltage supercapacitors in series to meet the minimum voltage, then paralleled to make the required minimum capacitance.
For example, you would need about 2300 of Amazon's 4 Farad 5.5 Volt units at an approximate cost of $10,000.

The voltage at swap time Varies from a full voltage battery  at 84v down to 60v. Having a battery on board or ready to plug in is challenging in itself, because the voltage can't change that quickly in Lithium batteries. It would take the correct circuit to work properly.

As pointed out by Phil's answer, the amount of super-capacitors for such high current for so long is not very realistic.
One option might be to have a small (fixed) lithium battery that handles the transition. You don't need much capacity (5 A for 15 s = 5*15/60/60= 0.02 Ah), but you require a somewhat big current (compared to the capacity).
You can probably use the smallest capacity you can find in 20S (just check the current rating).
An alternative, that might be cheaper, is to use a low(er) voltage battery for the swapping, and a DC-DC converter to maintain the correct voltage.
If you can, I think the best solution is to follow Neil's route:
connect the 2nd battery before disconnecting the 1st.
If your only issue is that the full battery will try to charge the empty one with high currents, then you just need to add a diode on the + connection of each battery to block reverse currents (size it properly for heat dissipation). I would recommend you use a Schottky diode (lower voltage drop), or if you do your own PCB, then even better, an "ideal diode" made of a MOSFET + ideal diode driver (voltage drop an order of magnitude smaller, so far less power losses/heat to dissipate).
If you fear to have a big inrush current because your system itself will react this way, then there are special hot swap ICs with integrated inrush current limitation (some integrate the MOSFETs, some drive external MOSFETs).

It is possible to turn off some of the back ground power draw while swapping the battery. One water pump and two Air colling fans are generally  running at the time of the swaps. Total of about 3 amps. I am not 100% sure of the amp draw of the controller alone, but would guess it is under 1 amp. The controller has internal caps the can keep it running for about 4 seconds with the pump running.


Plugging another battery into the system before removing the discharged on will not work because we never know exactly what the voltage will be. To much of a spike or discharge for a lithium battery.

... unless you treat the unknown voltage of the battery as you would have to treat the variable voltage of the supercaps, and use it to drive a DC-DC converter
... or given the high voltages involved, >65 V, a diode drop would be little loss of efficiency, and you could simply diode-OR the batteries.
If you're worried about the sudden rise of bus voltage from 65 V to 84 V, then a series pass FET per battery supply could be used to make the transition as smooth as you like. Two FETs would be a lot cheaper than a bank of supercaps.

Would that require a DC Converter from (example) 72v to 12v (battery) and then a DC Converter to go back up 12v to 72v?

@MarkPeroni There are so many ways to solve this particular issue that I struggle to see the problem. Have a 'transfer battery' - small, high C rate, with a DC-DC converter up to match whatever your battery bus is, far cheaper cost per Wh than supercaps. I've added to my question two ways you can simply connect the full battery into the equipment before removing the old one. Where does the 12 V come from in your comment?

The idea of using a smaller 12v battery DC-DC converter up to 72 volts sounds feasible. We would need to use a switch to go back and forth as mentioned above.

12 v comes in as a smaller battery to keep on board to run the transfer power. Instead of  a full 72v battery. Using 72v as a nominal number for the battery. Fully charged is 84v.
